# Sending argument to 'help' function

Tags: function, matlab, arguments

How can you send an argument to the `help` function?

I wish to have something like this:

```
function intro(funcname)
  disp('This is an introduction to the function you chose. See the help below:')
  help funcname
end
```

where I can show the help text for a function, which name comes as an argument in the function. The above does not work though, when MatLab just searches for `funcname` as a function name and not the variable value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short:** Yes, you can do it, by using the function form of `help`:

```
  x = 'mean';
  help(x);
```

In your example:

```
function intro(funcname)
  disp('This is an introduction to the function you chose. See the help below:')
  help(funcname);
end
```

**Explanation:**
The form that you are using

```
help xxx
```

is merely a shortcut to:

```
 help('xxx');
```

If you have multiple arguments separated by space (Thanks to @Amro on this one), it is the same like sending multiple arguments:
For example:

```
mcc -m fileNames
```

is equal to

```
mcc('-m','fileNames');
```

As a side note that represents my opinion, I would like to add that in general, the second form is preferred, except when you write a quick-and-dirty code.

Comment: why do you think `mcc` is a special case? (as far as I know, it is just another MEX function)

Comment: @Amro , well, mainly because I tried once and it didn't work out

Comment: I can assure you it works just like any other function (though most of its arguments start with a dash: `mcc('-m','myfunction')`)

Comment: @Amro, oh that might be the problem! I tried `mcc('-m myfunction')`. Let me check this out. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @Amro Thanks! It works. That will really help me. I just need to update my answer now

Comment: For what it's worth, here is a link to the relevant section in the documentation: [Command vs. Function Syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/f7-58289.html)